# please how to change color in php code in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have this code to hide price in woocommerce until user login i want to change the message color that will appear "login to see price" the code is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_hide_price_addcart_not_logged_in', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_hide_price_addcart_not_logged_in( $price, $product ) {

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

   $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'login to see price', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}

return $price;

}
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? WHat have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just add *style="color:yourcolor"* to link section, example

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_hide_price_addcart_not_logged_in', 9999, 2 );
function bbloomer_hide_price_addcart_not_logged_in( $price, $product ) {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {


        $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '" style="color:red">' . __( 'login to see price', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: thanks but what ı meant to do ıs i want to change text color
this text that will appear when user is not logged on
   $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'login to see price', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';
in this code the message is "login to see price"i wanna this message in red

Comment: Just add style="color : red" to  link section

Comment: You're welcome, please give me an upvote and mark the answer as solving the question.

Comment: really i do not know how to do this since i am newbie with satckflow